# How to calculate permutation $(12)^{-1}(12345)(12)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

I was wondering if someone could help me find $(12)^{-1}(12345)(12)$

I need to know this for calculating conjucacy classes and then a character table, thanks

Comment: Hint: $(12)^{-1}=(12)$.

Comment: Write 12345 in a line. On the next line write the result of swapping 1,2. So you get 21345. On the third line write the result of cycling 12345, So you get 32451. On the fourth line write the result of swapping 12, giving 31452. Now compare the first line with the last. That is your permutation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends, do you compute from left to right or right to left.  Many modern books treat permutations as left actions on the set $\{1,\cdots,n\}$, while some older books (e.g. Herstein) multiply in the opposite order.  Also, how the premutation is read in the parentheses also differs between treatments, whether it should be read from left-to-right or right-to-left. Treating this as a left action where the map is read from left to right, you can track elements as follows:

- $(12)$ Exchanges $1$ and $2$ while keeping $3$, $4$, and $5$ fixed.
- $(12345)$ Maps $1$ to $2$, $2$ to $3$, $3$ to $4$, $4$ to $5$, and $5$ to $1$.

(1) Start with $1$, reading from right-to-left, $(12)$ turns $1$ into $2$.  Then $(12345)$ turns $2$ into $3$.  Finally, $(12)^{-1}=(12)$ doesn't affect $3$ since $3$ doesn't appear, so the entire permutation takes $1$ and maps it to $3$.  This means that the permutation starts $(13\cdots)\cdots$.

(3) Continuing with $3$, $(12)$ has no effect on $3$, so we turn to $(12345)$ which takes $3$ to $4$.  Since $(12)^{-1}=(12)$ has no effect on $4$, this permutation maps $3$ to $4$.  Therefore, the permutation (as computed so far) is $(134\cdots)\cdots$.

(4) Continuing with $4$, $(12)$ has no effect on $4$, so we turn to $(12345)$ which takes $4$ to $5$.  Since $(12)^{-1}=(12)$ has no effect on $5$, this permutation maps $4$ to $5$.  Therefore, the permutation (as computed so far) is $(1345\cdots)\cdots$.

(4) Continuing with $5$, $(12)$ has no effect on $5$, so we turn to $(12345)$ which takes $5$ to $1$.  Since $(12)^{-1}=(12)$ maps $1$ to $2$, this permutation maps $5$ to $2$.  Therefore, the permutation (as computed so far) is $(13452\cdots)\cdots$.  However, since there are only $5$ elements and we have considered all of them (we don't need to study the behavior of $2$ since permutations are bijections), the conjugate permutation is $(13452)$.

Comment: Thank you this is really clear. Just one thing, after we 'start with 1' why do we consider 3 next, and not 2?

Comment: Oh, its because it is now in 2nd place

Comment: I think I understand now :)

Comment: Because the output of $1$ was $3$, so $3$ is next (the cycle notation shows what's next, in order).  If you wrap around and haven't used up all the possible values, start a new cycle with the first one that hasn't appeared yet.

Answer (score -1):

Since you mentioned calculating conjugacy classes, here's a neat trick for conjugation you should find useful:

For any permutation $\sigma$ and any cycle $(a_1~ \ldots~ a_n)$, it is true that $$\sigma \circ (a_1~\ldots~a_n) \circ \sigma^{-1} = (\sigma(a_1)~\ldots~\sigma(a_n)).$$

Therefore $$(1~2)^{-1}\circ(1~2~3~4~5~)\circ (1~2) = (2~1~3~4~5).$$